# Is it weird to ask a professor you don't know if your potential project is already being worked on?

Tags: etiquette

I am a graduate student in physics who has an idea for a project which I believe to be sound. It is outside my advisor's area of expertise, but I am reasonably familiar with the field. My main concern with this project is how obvious of an extension of recent work it appears to be, and I suspect that someone out there has likely thought of a similar idea and is currently working on it as well. Would it be inappropriate to email a professor who's more well-versed in the field and ask if they're aware of anyone who has begun working on a similar project?

Comment: Hmmm. Would they say no and then immediately start work on it?

Comment: Maybe? I guess that can't be helped. They seem like a reasonable enough person and I would hope they would at least be open to collaboration. That may not be the case, but I think it would be a risk I'm willing to take given the context.

Comment: Some random professor? or someone in your dept?

Comment: Not in my department, but at a nearby university.

Comment: In general, the question 'is this new?' always exists for all research projects.  I may have an idea, and to my best effort, Google doesn't come up with anything similar. So I assume it is 'safe' to move forward.  However, there is always an inkling that I might have missed something, or that the keywords I used are incorrect; someone called an apple something else for example.  Another possibility is that the idea exists in a non-English publication.  So you are never sure.  You just move forward when you are sufficiently confident and hope for the best.

Comment: If by 'recent work' you mean a particular single recent paper, you should email the authors of that paper.  That's because they will be the natural people for anyone to ask this question to.

Answer (score 7):

> Would it be inappropriate to email a professor who's more well-versed in the field and ask if they're aware of anyone who has begun working on a similar project?

Absolutely not, I'd say. I've emailed several professors from different schools, textbook authors, and other people. While you may not get a reply (that's ok!) it takes zero effort to write and the pay off can be large. You're not going to offend someone by sending a nicely worded email inquiring about their field. If they don't care to answer they won't. So why not?

Comment: What about https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155674/is-it-weird-to-ask-a-professor-you-dont-know-if-your-potential-project-is-alrea#comment416429_155674 ?